# Как обратиться к картинке, лежащей на несколько уровней выше?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Уже битый час ломаю голову над задачей: обратиться к картинке, лежащей на несколько уровней выше.

HTML:

```
       <div class="portfolio-item photo">
          <div class="portfolio-info">
            <span class="info">
              <h3>Название проекта</h3>
              <p>Web-сайт</p>
              <hr>
              <div class="btn-open-img" href="#"></div>
            </span>
          </div>
          <img src="img/photo/001.jpg" alt="Photo 1">
        </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".btn-open-img").click(function(){
  var img = $(this); // тут надо
});
```

Нужно получить в переменную "img" не кнопку (.btn-open-img), а "". Это необходимо будет, чтобы получить путь картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".btn-open-img").click(function(){
  var img = $(this).closest(".portfolio-item").find("img"); // тут надо
});
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!) Только познаю JS, не все понимаю до конца.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".btn-open-img").click(function(){
  var img = $(this).closest(".portfolio-item").find("img"); // тут надо
  console.log("src", img.attr('src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="portfolio-item photo">
  <div class="portfolio-info">
    <span class="info">
      <h3>Название проекта</h3>
      <p>Web-сайт</p>
      <hr>
      <a class="btn-open-img" href="#">click me</a>
    </span>
  </div>
  <img src="img/photo/001.jpg" alt="Photo 1">
</div>
```